# URLRequest POST doesn't work in Swift 5. There may be a problem with the server?

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
    let parametrs = ["word": newWord.word, "translate": newWord.translate , "studied" :newWord.studied] as [String : Any]

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parametrs, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response
        {
            print(response)
        }
        print(parametrs)
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do
        {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
```

I think the problem is server related

NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000029d240

{ URL: http://pavlo-tymoshchuk-inc.right-k-left.com/wordList.json } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" =     (
        bytes
    );
    Connection =     (
        "Upgrade, Keep-Alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        6689
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 07 Feb 2020 00:21:32 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=15, max=100"
    );
    "Last-Modified" =     (
        "Thu, 06 Feb 2020 22:55:22 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
    Upgrade =     (
        "h2,h2c"
    );
} }
["word": "aaa", "translate": ["aaa"], "studied": false]

Comment: You are getting a response back with status code = 200, which implies the server is working just fine. What's the exact problem you are having?

Comment: Unfortunately, data is not being written to the server to file

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to make the data be added to the json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong here.

- Status 200
- code doesn’t test for error but I bet it’s nil
- Print of response is what you should expect
- Print JSON prints a json object.

You should be happy. Or What would you expect?

Comment: Unfortunately, data is not being written to the server to file

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to make the data be added to the json file

Comment: This comment (json file) gives a hint: If I look at your server's root output (http://pavlo-tymoshchuk-inc.right-k-left.com/) it looks to me as if it was plain json files that would be served. Do you actually have a backend coded, that would receive your request and store POSTed data?

Comment: Oh, thank you, I understand. No, I do not have a backend coded. Could you tell how to do this?

Comment: Maybe a bit too involved to fit a SO post ;) Google may be your friend.  Maybe you need some overview over the general architecture of a web app (front/backend). After that I would search for tutorials on backend development. Make sure to get educated about different programming languages before you actually start coding so you find out what suits your needs best. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer